# Doxygen can't parse C function pointer signature

Tags: c, function-pointers, doxygen

Doxygen (1.8.6) won't parse this, for me:

```
/**
  @fn dynArray* dynMap(dynArray* array, void*(*callback)(void**, size_t, dynArray*))
  @brief foo
  @param array    bar
  @param callback baz

  blah blah blah
*/
extern dynArray* dynMap(dynArray*, void*(*)(void**, size_t, dynArray*));
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? I notice that if I remove the argument names from the documentation, it will compile, albeit incorrectly (it mangles the parameters). However, it *does* work if I match the documentation to the signature exactly:

```
/**
  @fn dynArray* dynMap(dynArray* array, void*(*callback)(void**, size_t, dynArray*))
  @brief foo
  @param array    bar
  @param callback baz

  blah blah blah
*/
extern dynArray* dynMap(dynArray* array, void*(*callback)(void**, size_t, dynArray*));
```

However, then I get `array` and `callback` in the type definitions for the function, which isn't particularly satisfying...

Comment: What happens if you define a typedef for the function pointer type, and use that in the declaration of the function? (There are other benefits of using a typedef in this case, readability for one.)

Comment: I'll move to typedef's for the sake of readability. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `@fn` while the symbol you want to document is right after the comment block? That is not needed at all.

If you somehow cannot suppress the urge to use `@fn` then you should indeed match the arguments with the declaration (or you could move the comment block to the function definition).

See also http://www.doxygen.org/manual/docblocks.html#structuralcommands for more info

When working with function pointers it is usually a good practice to typedef them.

Comment: I'm new to Doxygen and, given its size, found it easier to just "dive in"; hence my using `@fn` without realising I didn't need to. If I remove the `@fn` line, it works but it mangles the parameters in the output's header, as they're not defined in the declaration... I'll move to typedef'd function pointers, for the reasons you and @Lindydancer mention.